# What exactly do the different Spaceship components do in Civ Revolution?

Tags: civilization-revolution

In the end game for Civilization Revolution on the iPad, I'm presented with the option to build

- SS Fuel Pod
- SS Propulsion
- SS Life Support
- SS Habitation

The first two are described as "Will reduce the time required to reach its destination" and the last two as "Will increase final score on its arrival".

These all somehow add up to Propulsion (in "pounds of thrust"), Station Weight (in "tons"), travel time (in years, of course), and colonists at arrival, in some number out of some other number.

I know it's just a silly endgame thing, but if I wanted to, say, get 100000 colonists to Alpha Centauri in the shortest amount of time, and have a *lot* of building resources due to a large empire, what should I put together (and how would I figure it out)?

Comment: Pretty sure there is a maximum number of components you can build.

Comment: @fbueckert It definitely lets you keep building 'em forever, but there may be some limit on actually having an effect.